# How to use the java agent of opentelemetry to actively obtain traceId

Tags: java, open-telemetry

I want to return the traceId when the user reports an error in my springboot project, so that I can troubleshoot the error, but I use the javaagent of opentelemetry, and I haven't found a way to get the traceId in my project. So is there a way to get this traceId in my global exception handler?

I hope to be able to get the traceId inside my project and return the traceId to the user when an exception is thrown

Answer (score 2):

This should give you the current span's trace id:

```
import io.opentelemetry.api.trace.Span

Span.current().getSpanContext().getTraceId()
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether this is something you'd want included in all logs, you could add different trace details from the MDC to log lines via springboot config:

> logging.pattern.level = trace_id=%mdc{trace_id} span_id=%mdc{span_id}
> trace_flags=%mdc{trace_flags} %5p

[source](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/main/docs/logger-mdc-instrumentation.md)